# Anylogic - Creating an Elevator System with Pedestrians

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am currently trying to recreate my university dorm elevator system in AnyLogic, however I am unsure how to even start with pedestrians and elevators, as the lifts in the program are only used by transporter fleets.

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to do elevators, you will have to code that yourself. It is possible but requires fairly advanced skills in OOP and coding. Here is an [example using elevators](https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/78d1f8ac-cf3f-4126-b5e4-cbbde700e20d?mode=SETTINGS) to get you started.